# dynamically add hidden inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I add dynamically with jquery a hidden input field populated with values to my table row on option select. The functon is getting executed but the probelm is that on new select is not getting overriden on each option select a new input field is getting added. The other issue would be each time I get 2 ipnut fields added. My code looks like

```
    jQuery(".add_column").change('select',function(event){             
       var selected_column = $j(this).find(":selected").val();
       var selected_value  = $j(this).parent('tr').data('id');
       var column_type;
       $j(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            column_type = ($j(this).parent().attr("label") );                   
        });

       $j('<input/>',{type:'hidden',value:selected_value+'|'+selected_column , name:column_type+'[]'}).appendTo($j(this).parent('tr'));

    });
```

Comment: input field is getting added because you're adding an input field `$j('<input/>',...` Can you post the html to get a clear picture

Comment: second issue fixed, it was inside 2 change events. For the first issue I think I must remove on new select the input field and add a new one

Comment: of course you need to remove(), or if the `<option>`'s index is known, you can do `.eq(n).html()`

Comment: okay now I have problems to post the input array to my php script is getting messed on the way

Answer (score 0):

For security's reason, not use object syntax for constructing elements. You can use string constructor:

```
 $('<input name="inputs[]" type="hidden" value="'+value+'" />').appendTo('#inputs-content');
```

It's most advisable of this method.

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/zM8zy/  *(Open the browser console and inspect the DOM Elements for show the results)*